# How to Parse HTML as PHP?

Tags: php, html, apache, configuration

I'm using Apache2 on Heroku and I'm trying to parse HTML as PHP so I can include files inside a HTML file and use HTML as normal, so I don't have to copy paste the navigator and stuff, such as footer in each other html file. This makes work much easier.

I've tried to look things up, made .htaccess and httpd.conf work, but whatever I have done so far it doesn't really work. What it does at the moment is it gives me .html to download.

These are the current settings I have:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

I AddType started to cause the .html to download.

Inside httpd.conf I have this:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

```
<Files />
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

**Update:**

I've asked Heroku support, however, they don't support these things... uhm..

So, I've figured out that the buildpacks that Heroku has, this one: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

has a folder inside support that includes this:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/tree/master/support/build/_conf/apache2

a httpd.conf that I can't access, because apperantly it builds from that. However I can remove that buildpack and replace it with mine. The problem is the buildpacks work like that

they have a bin folder with a compiler inside, and when I fork it, it still compiles it from their repository.

I need someone to help me out and fork it and basically modify it so that it doesn't load a httpd.conf at all, so that I can include mine and do stuff with it.

**Update:**

I am just using PHP now, since I can't do anything to change it, it's on heroku's side or the buildpack from heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Your **AddType** seems to be ok:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Sometimes you need to indicate the PHP version:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

or for PHP 7:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php7 .html .htm
```

another solution is to remove html handler:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

one more solution:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

**Do not forget to restart the server to see the results!**

Comment: all what I can say is that what you gave me doesn't work, because I've tried them earlier, but I've never tried RemoveHandler so lemme try that. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I forgot something to mention that, https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/conf/apache2/heroku.conf
I am including an httpd.conf just I've tested that what you sent me or what I tested before in .htacces, basically heroku has some stuff already set so

Comment: ofc I removed addhandler to all of this

Comment: I am using php-fpm

Comment: maybe try to change `AddType` to `AddHandler ` as: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` or `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm`

Comment: or set it additionally in .htaccess

Comment: im not using discord :) ohhh. Firstly, try to set in in your `httpd.conf` file. If not working, experiment with `.htaccess`..,. for now delete it from `.htaccess` and try all solutions straight in `httpd.conf`

Comment: doing that right now, someone told me to try this https://pastebin.com/1TAbfPJE the thing is I don't know the vhost name and not sure how I get that from Heroku.

Comment: also all the solutions don't work in httpd.conf either

Comment: In my case: 1) no any references in `.htaccess`, 2) PHP handler added in 'httpd.conf': [https://pastebin.com/vVZDz81u](https://pastebin.com/vVZDz81u). I think if none of the solutions works, the problem is completely elsewhere ...

Comment: I found this in master Heroku https.config [https://pastebin.com/HaGNCTP2](https://pastebin.com/HaGNCTP2). Remove it all and try to put: [https://pastebin.com/A6KxbaDs](https://pastebin.com/A6KxbaDs)

Comment: Also remove all handlers from .htaccess

Comment: this didn't change anything also I can't remove stuff from httpd.config it includes it unless there is a special something like RemoveHandlers to do that
it stopped downloading .html but didn't parse php

Comment: I just tried it myself by replaces `<FilesMatch \.php$>` with `<FilesMatch "\.html$">` in `https.config`. Working fine. No handlers in `.htaccess`. I have no idea why it does not work with you ... it seems to me that the problem is deeper. Can you share content of your 'https.config' and '.htaccess'?

Comment: it's empty, but look, I use httpd-buildpack-apache2 -C httpd.conf which includes it inside the server, if I would be able to replace it I would do it but the thing is I have it on a Heroku webpage that I deploy from github, also it's called httpd.conf otherwise I get confused

Comment: ... I do not have any more ideas. In general, it is always quite simple. I will look for more information, and let u know  if I found any solution.

Comment: thanks, I'll look further too, but I will use just .php at the moment since it has html too.

Comment: Did you setup the Heroku PHP locally, I have it from a GitHub repo I believe if I can set it up locally or access the files to modify it so that doesn't happen, then I think it won't happen, that thing with the issue.

Comment: The only way to modify that, or idk, is to fork this https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php and modify it, because it builds from that url